# AngularJS, ng-repeat on radio and $scope.watch

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this example: https://jsfiddle.net/qnw8ogrk/1/ to create my radio-buttons.

I would like to be able to use $scope.watch on the radio-buttons, but I'm not able to use:

```
$scope.watch('selected', ...
```

What should I assign to .watch to be able to detect whenever a user clicks on a radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual mistake was `$scope.watch` should be `$scope.$watch` Having watcher over a scope variable would not be the good idea. Instead of placing watcher over `ng-model` I'd suggest you to use `ng-change` which will only fires up when radio button `ng-model` value gets changed.

```
<label ng-repeat="option in options">
   <input type="radio" ng-change="test()" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-value="option" />{{option}}
</label>
```

---

And then don't use get rid of `$parent` notation for accessing outer scope of `ng-repeat` you could switch to use `controllerAs` pattern, and then change ng-controller directive to use `alias` of controller. Also that will change the controller implementation, bind value to `this`(context) instead of `$scope`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as vm">
    <label ng-repeat="option in vm.options">
      <input type="radio" ng-change="vm.test()" ng-model="vm.selected" ng-value="option" />{{option}}
    </label>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
appModule.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selected = 'red';
  vm.options = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];
  vm.test = function() {
    alert('Changed');
  }
});
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](https://jsfiddle.net/z2cfouvx/)

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen Glad to help you. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @PankajParker, but it is possible from you controller as well. You just got the syntax wrong, it is `$scope.$watch`, not `$scope.watch`

Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/qnw8ogrk/32/

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/qnw8ogrk/33/

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <label ng-repeat="option in options">
            <input type="radio" ng-change="picked(this)" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-value="option"/>{{option}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var appModule = angular.module('app', []);

appModule.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.selected = 'red';
    $scope.options = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];
        $scope.picked = function($scope) {
        alert('you picked: ' + $scope.selected);
    }
});
```